# How to build write-heavy handler in golang and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, buffer

I have searched online greatly but I am not able to do find a good tutorial that teaches this. So I have decided to ask.
I am trying to build a write-intensive application in golang for events (json) and I don't know how to go about it. I have looked through the bufio documentation but I don't seem to know how to approach it. My idea is that I should create a buffer where I can store these json events as they come, until the buffer is full, then I empty it to a mongodb bulkwrite method

In pseudo code, I expect something like this

```
func receiveWriteData(conn) {
    jsonData := conn.readJson() // to get the current json that has come into this tcp port
    getBuffer := currentExistingBuffer()
    getBuffer.addToBuffer(jsonData)
    dataToBulkWrite := []modelType{}

    if getBuffer.isFull() {
        gatheredData = getBuffer.Flush()
        for data in gatheredData {
            dataToBulkWrite.append(data)
        }
        mongoDB.bulkWrite(dataToBulkWrite)
    }
```

This is just in pseudo code. I would really appreciate is you can give me the golang equivalent.

I have been able to get string data using the code below

```
message, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error reading:", err.Error())
}
fmt.Print("Message Received from the client: ", string(message))
conn.Close()
```

But this does not handle my use case

Comment: It's super hard to answer this question, there's so many ways this could be implemented. The problem I see with your pseudocode is that it will block when the buffer is full. 

One approach would be to 1. Create a go channel, 2. Have your handler decode messages and push them to this channel 3. Have a goroutine that receives from the channel and write either when some number of event is reached or when some time has passed. This way the handler wouldn't block.

Comment: Fantastic idea, thanks a lot. Will do that right away. I am new to golang so my thinking is still very pythonic

Comment: Hi @LudovicC I am having trouble thinking about how to persist the channel to accept multiple data input from the same tcp connection, I don't seem to be getting the code right. I can post what I have tried, but it's not working. Can you kindly post what the solution would look like? or atleast point me to a tutorial

Comment: sure! I can try to help